# Ender 3 Pro extruder keeps clogging

Tags: extruder, filament-jam

I'm fairly new to 3D printing and looking for help. I have an Ender 3 Pro and it's been working great up until about a week ago. When I preheat the extruder, the nozzle gets hot as it should, but it keeps jamming mid-print. About an hour in, the filament stops feeding. The gears are still trying to push it through, but it won't go.

After a bunch of troubleshooting, I eventually unscrewed the fitting where the tubing and filament enter, and even with the nozzle still fully heated up to 205-215 °C, there's a cooled, solid blob of filament sitting in what I believe is the heat sink (just above where it goes into the nozzle).

Does anyone know why this would happen? I'm using new filament, but I've tried 3 different spools all with the same result.

Comment: Did you clean the nozzle?

Comment: In order to solve this we may require some additional information. Please post photo's and printer settings, we have a nice [template](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/helpful-templates-help-us-help-you) available with the basic information. This sounds like heat creep, but we know for sure if we see photo's of the print and the print settings.

Comment: The nozzle has been both cleaned and replaced, twice. I'm using similar settings I've used before for the same prints. The only difference is it's new filament, but I've tried cranking the nozzle temp all the way up to 215 and it will still get a clog.